# Chaining prototypes and prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Person(name){
    this.name=name
}
var julia=new Person("Julia");

Person.prototype.sayName=function(){
return "Hello, dear "+ this.name;
}

function Other(name){
this.name=name;
}

var mike=new Other("Mike");

Other.prototype=Object.create(Person.prototype);
mike.sayName();
```

When I call mike.sayName(); it doesn't work and I get mike.sayName is not a function.
I dont understand why? By using Object.create I let Other.prototype inherit from the Person prototype which had the method sayName. Now, why am I not being able to run  mike.sayName();

Thanks!!!

Comment: Set `Other.prototype` before using `new Other`

Answer (score 1):

The `prototype` property of a constructor is only special because it's used as the [[Prototype]] value when creating instances. However, replacing `prototype` with another object will only affect instances created after the change, it won't magically update the [[Prototype]] of existing instances.

```
var oldproto = Other.prototype;
var mike = new Other("Mike");
Object.getPrototypeOf(mike); // oldproto
Other.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Object.getPrototypeOf(mike); // oldproto
```

So just swap the order:

```
Other.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
var mike = new Other("Mike");
```

Comment: Can you explain why? Im surprised because in caseof Person-I create FIRST the instance julia, then AFTERWARDS I create the Person.prototype and the new object julia still has access to the Person.prototype method. However, mike does not.

Comment: That's because one thing is adding a method to an existing object, and another one is replacing an object with another one.

Comment: @juliascoding You should accept the answer if satisfied with it.